# ERROR running force:org:create: We don’t recognize this namespace: x. Did you register it in your Dev Hub org?

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, scratch-org, namespace, 2gp

I am trying to create a `Scratch Org` with a `Namespace` using command:

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a my-namespace -d 30
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR running force:org:create: We don’t recognize this namespace: my-namespace. Did you register it in your Dev Hub org?

I realise what the error message is telling me...

I need to create the `Namespace`.

I want to double-check my understanding of the solution is correct.

Currently, creating a `Namespace` is only possible via a traditional `Developer Org` rather than a `Scratch Org` or just via the `Namespace Registries` page in my `Dev Hub Org`

Therefore, there is no way to develop a `2PG` `Managed Package` without first using an old school `Developer Org` to create the `Namespace`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_create_namespace.htm) specifically says:

> Sign up for a new Developer Edition org

I.e. you are right; you must have an org on which the namespace is defined and the (recommended) way of doing that is to use a new Developer Edition org, then to link that namespace to your dev hub.

For us we use a specific pattern for the org name to ensure they are listed in our PBO's Environment Hub together.

Comment: The last line in your answer is a best practice that you follow to efficiently manage both 1GP as well as 2GP in your production org and not really something strictly to be followed from scratch org point of view, right? I would prefer not to get confused by the usage of the term Environment Hub when talking about 2GP. So, this is just for my understanding.

Comment: You still need to keep the dev org with the namespace, so having it in the env hub makes sense to me. (The dev hub being something different, but actually also being the PBO itself.)

Comment: Oh, and scratch orgs are quite a separate thing again.

Comment: That's right. In second generation packaging, while the dev orgs with namespace needs to be maintained, the namespace registry would be used to manage the namespaces (where it can be on a separate Dev Hub or PBO as Dev Hub). **_Environment Hub would be something completely different and relevant exclusively to first generation packaging. So, unless you are managing a mix of 1GP & 2GP in your production env, there wouldn't be a need for Env Hub_**. Since, the question was tagged as 2GP, I felt that mentioning about Env Hub could be confusing. Does that make sense?

Comment: You want the developer org to be in your environment hub for management and access purposes. You don't want to loose the org...

Comment: Guess I had a minor misunderstanding of your answer and I see your point now. For creating and managing partner dev orgs, trial orgs etc. efficiently, one would still want to continue using Environment Hub (_although for someone starting as a new partner, they may be completely get away with just using 'scratch orgs' and 'developer orgs created outside Env Hub', as there is no restriction imposed to create developer orgs only via Env Hub_). Also, I guess my comments are drifting away from the main question and I'm likely to get advised by other members about any further comments :).